# Excel VBA Userforms: How do I transfer data from a List Box to a worksheet cell?

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform

I have a ListBox with three options: Cylinder, Ellipsoid, and Frustum. The User chooses one of these and hits the submit button. What I would like to do is write their choice in a cell on my worksheet when the submit button is clicked. How do I do this?

Comment: Simply write Range("A1").Value = ListBox1.Text or Range("A1").Value = ListBox1.Value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ListBox Control object will have some name. So if your form is called `frm` and the listbox object is named `lstBox`, you would move its selected value to a range, `myRange` like this:

`myRange.value = frm.lstBox.text`

If you wanted to loop through cells in a range if would look something like:

```
Dim cell as range

For each cell in myRange
    cell.value = frm.lstBox.text
next cell
```

The above would write the value in the ListBox to each cell in the range.

Comment: Would writing values in cells this way overwrite the cell or continue down with each submission?

Comment: it would overwrite unless you have some loop that iterates over the range you want to write to

Comment: Do you have a link to a loop written for this reason or a similar loop? I'm familiar with loops in other languages but I don't know how to format/structure them in VBA. If not that's fine, I'll just do some more googling.

Comment: @Skye I added a little example code block in my answer. Is that similar to what you are after?